# Qt:Unable to set Background color for qComboBox properly

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qt5.9

I have a QCombobox and I want to set a white background color.This is my code.

```
QComboBox *cBox = new QComboBox;
cBox->addItem("Text1");
cBox->setStyleSheet("background-color:white");
```

This combobox has a parent widget whose background is an image and is set as given below:

```
ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(./image.png)");
```

When I set the parent Widget[centralWidget] background as some other color,then the white BG works properly for the combobox.But when I set an image as the parent Widget background,the UI looks like this.[image: the below]

In the above pic,the black Bg is an image.Could someone highlight me what am I missing.Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: Have you set the stylesheet in another part of your code? If you have, show it.

Comment: Nope..I set the stylesheet here only..

Comment: So how have you established that your widgets have a black background?

Comment: The parent widget of the layout inside which this combobox exists has a black background color

Comment: What's the platform? And How did you set the background colour?

Comment: I work in Ubuntu 16.04..and I have set the BG the same way as above to the parent widget

Comment: @adi provide a [mcve]

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-styles-example.html

Comment: Actually when I set the parent Widget background as some other color,then the white BG works properly for the combobox.But when I set an image as the  parent Widget background,it is as shown above.I used the following for setting the parent widget BG:             ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image:url(./image.png)");

Comment: please edit the question to add code instead comment.

Comment: @adi try with: `ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget#centralWidget{ border-image:url(./image.png)}");`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks man..It works..Could u pls brief what is it so that I can understand and could u add this as answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not indicate to which widget you are going to apply some property, they will be applied to all your children, for this reason the same `QComboBox` background image is applied to the child of `centralWidget`.

In your case you want to apply only to the centralWidget, and by default Qt Designer uses the same name for the name of the variable that represents the widget and the objectName.

[image]

So if you want to apply to a widget we can use the objectName as [selector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types):

```
QWidget#centralWidget{ border-image:url(./image.png)}
```

Comment: Could you tell me which is the better way to setBackground?stylesheets or QPalette?? What is the difference?

Comment: @adi Could you mark it as correct? The author of the question, I mean, is the only one who can do it, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]

Comment: oops Im not aware of it..Could u pls tell me which is the better way to setBackground?stylesheets or QPalette??

Comment: @adi ***What is the difference?***, are 2 ways to do it, 
each one has its advantage, for example qss is very similar to css (to css2.1 to be exact) so you could create a .qss file where you put all styles using selectors, etc. Or on the other hand use QPallete, not only is the only way, you could also use QStyle.

Comment: But is that like no matter  what approach we take for setting Background,all are inherited by the children widgets by default?

Comment: @adi no, QPalette does not have the idea of ​​hierarchy

Comment: So if my understanding is right:1.Use QPalette to a widget if its children doesn't want to inherit the BG 2.Use QStyle / StyleSheets to a widget if its children want to inherit the BG.Am I right?

Comment: @adi 
with Qt Style Sheet you can also apply to a single widget but for this you must use the selectors, read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

Comment: In some cases,if I set BG using selector for the Parent Widget like u have specified,the combox box becomes white but the image disappears?What shall be done in that event?

Comment: @adi 
I do not understand you, if you provide a [mcve] I could help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177725/discussion-between-adi-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: I have an issue reproduceable code.how shall I show you the code?Becoz the answer above works fine with the case posted!!so editing the question might not be gud..,but my issue reproducing code is with dynamic widgets .

Comment: @adi 
then create another post