# Qt:Unable to set Background color for qwidget with a Parent Background Image

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qtstylesheets, qt5.9

I have a QWidget (basically a QComboBox) to which Im setting a background color(white).This QComboBox has a parent widget which has a background Image.
And the output looks like this:

[image]

The combobox is not completely white and has some impact of the parent BG image.I have posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742821/qtunable-to-set-background-color-for-qcombobox-properly/51760081#51760081) wherein I used QtCreator and it works with the provided solution.

But when I try to create the widgets dynamically with the same solution,the BG image is getting disappeared.

Below is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

QPixmap bkgnd("blue_bg.png");
bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
this->setPalette(palette);

QHBoxLayout* hbl = new QHBoxLayout(this);

QWidget *black = new QWidget;
black->setMaximumHeight(200);
black->setStyleSheet ("border-image:url(black_bg.png)");
//black->setStyleSheet ("QWidget#black{ border-image:url(black_bg.png)}");
//I tried this as per the link's answer but this hides/removes the black_bg.png image itself

hbl->addWidget(black);
f1(black);
}

void MainWindow::f1(QWidget *black)
{

QVBoxLayout *blackLayout = new QVBoxLayout(black);

QHBoxLayout *comboBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

QLabel *comboBoxLabel = new QLabel("Label");
comboBoxLabel->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
comboBoxLabel->setStyleSheet("color:white");
comboBoxLabel->setMaximumWidth(300);
comboBoxLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
comboBoxLayout->addWidget(comboBoxLabel);


QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox;
comboBox->addItem("String");
comboBox->setMaximumHeight(500);
comboBoxLayout->addWidget(comboBox);
blackLayout->addLayout(comboBoxLayout);

}
```

Comment: set `black->setObjectName("black");` before `black->setStyleSheet("QWidget#black{ border-image:url(black_bg.png)}");`

Comment: Hey thank u man!!!What is the default object name?Could you recommend some tutorials/blogs to understand these concepts other than the Qt documenation...

Comment: If you create it by code the objectName is `""`, if you use Qt Designer you can see it in the properties, just read the docs, there are a lot of examples.

Comment: or you can set object name by using setObjectName method from code.